# Localhost files and references to REST server

Tags: macos, apache2

I have a website that was setup to test/debug on a remote server which also runs ServiceStack. I am transitioning my workflow to allow me to test locally instead. I've got my virtual host working and pointing to my files correctly, but I can't access the data without changing all my references to ServiceStack in my code.

Here is the initial remote setup: http://testserver/ is the web server and the directory /svc/ is ServiceStack. So when I need data, I basically call $.ajax('/svc/servicename') to get JSON data back.

Locally that won't work, obviously, because there is no /svc/ directory and no ServiceStack. Is there a way to set up another virtual host, or a sym link, or another option so a /svc/ directory (locally) can point to http://testserver/svc/ to receive the data? I got past the cross domain issue, so I don't have to worry about that.

Basically, I am trying to keep my local files unchanged as much as possible so when I move them to the live server, everything works. I don't want to change all the references of "/svs/servicename" to "http://testserver/svc/servicename" and then back again when I need to publish.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

edit: 
I've tried adding a RedirectMatch in the httpd-vhosts.conf and it seems to be doing the redirect, but I am getting an error in my ajax call and a status of "302 Found". I have this in the virtual host definition for my localhost site:

```
RedirectMatch "^/svc/(.*)" "http://testserver/svc/$1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work without changing anything in my source files. All was done in the httpd-vhosts.conf file. Basically I had to add ProxyPass in the virtual host definition...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localtest.com
    ServerAlias www.localtest.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/ME/Site1/"
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localtest.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localtest.com-access_log" common
    ServerAdmin web@localtest.com
    ProxyPass "/svc" "http://testserver/svc"     <------- this line!
</VirtualHost>
```